# How do I get x and y coords of the mouse individually?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to print the `x` position of my mouse without the `y` position.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
print(mouse)
```

This prints the `x` and `y` of the mouse as a tuple but I want to just print the `x`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply [unpack](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) your tuples:

```
x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```

Comment: Thanks! is there another way because i would need them also in a tuple later on?

Comment: You can unpack at any time, and you can also index tuples. E.g. `pair = mouse.get_pos()`, then later `x,y = pair` or `y = pair[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
print(mouse[0]) #prints x
print(mouse[1]) #prints y
```

You can access tuples like you access arrays

Comment: Thank you so much that is just what i needed

Answer (score 0):

`pygame.mouse.get_pos()` returns the tuple `(x,y)`. To get `x` and `y`, unpack the tuple:

`x, y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()`

To access the tuple, you can build it again with `x` and `y` or save it with `mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()`